# ModRewrite: QUERY_STRING not redirecting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rules in place:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^manufacturer=&
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=410,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to redirect with URL's like 
`http://www.example.com/?manufacturer=someone` to `http://www.example.com/` and `page.php?manufacturer=someone` to `page.php`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I have mod_rewite enabled and AllowOverride All in my site config
The above code is in the .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query string `^manufacturer=&` only matches manufacturer parameters that are **empty** and it also requires that the equals sign is followed by an ampersand which doesn't seem to be your wanted behaviour.

By the way, you do realize the [status code 410](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) means that the resource is *Gone* (indicates that the resource requested is no longer available and will not be available again)?

You seem to want to redirect back to the current page *without* the query parameter, so I suggest using a 302 or 301 redirect instead.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^manufacturer=.+$
RewriteRule .* $0? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I forgot to mark this as the correct answer before. Works fine, thanks. I did want to return 410 because these pages have actually gone and not moved, mainly for the benefit of Google.